# How to fix page so it displays correctly in IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, alignment

A reader has just brought to my attention that IE7 on Windows XP Professional, ver 2002, SP 2 displays pages such as http://beachpaper.com/issues/current/page28.html to look like beachpaper.com/zimgnav/bperror.jpg, by pushing the large JPG to the right. However, the home page, beachpaper.com, displays correctly for him and it's built from the same template. I built it using GoLive on a Mac and it looks fine in that outdated IE and all other browsers I've ever tried, so I'm at a loss at what to do. I ran it through the W3C validator and didn't see any likely suspects. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "How to fix page so it displays correctly in IE7?" is like "What is the meaning of life?" One of the great unsolvable puzzles ;)

Comment: Try fixing the validation errors first, then look back to IE.

Comment: I always laugh when developers complain and make light of the fact it takes actual work to make a finished product work with the prospective users.  That's effectively what we are paid to do.  Saying IE is any more wrong than Firefox or Safari with displaying content doesn't take into account that none of the browsers actually implement the W3C correctly regardless of what you have led yourself to believe.

Comment: And what code ((x)html and css) would you be using..? If we can see what you're trying to do (with the code), we might see why it's not working in IE7...

Comment: @CSharperWithJava, I think that if you give your customers/consumers the answer 'Use Firefox' you'll probably find yourself with fewer customers/consumers. ...though this may be a good thing if they're the sort that use (outdated) IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to a page on your site that didn't display correctly in IE, saved the source and DL'd the CSS and applied it to the page... and I've got the issue duplicated.

And I think I found the problem.

The following line is causing the issue:

```
<td rowspan="3" colspan="3" valign="top" width="800"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Region" -->
```

If you remove the colspan="3" call, and make it look like this:

```
<td rowspan="3" valign="top" width="800"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="Region" -->
```

Well, then everything displays properly for me.

I'd like to spend more time on it, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from the limited information you've provided (and possibly hard to tell without seeing your entire source), but perhaps a tool like Firebug (or [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html), since you're on IE) can help you out. I've found that a small amount of real-time CSS editing solves most problems I encounter.